# C# forms Cannot perform operation = on string and int

Tags: c#, string, integer

I have this populate table class. I get the error cannot perform operation of string and int. What am I doing wrong?

I am trying to get the data based on the Md_id which is the row number of the clicked row in the `datagridview1` and display the ff. data in the `datagridview2`. But gets the error below because of the row.

```
view.RowFilter = "MD_ID = " + MdNum ;
```

Below is my code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //get Md_id based on the row
    String MdNum = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

    //populate datagridview2
    XMLLevel2PopulateTable(MdNum.ToString());
}

private void XMLLevel2PopulateTable(string MdNum)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = ds.Tables["Tables"];
    DataView view = new DataView(dt);
    view.RowFilter = "MD_ID = " + MdNum ; // error here with mdNum
    dataGridView2.DataSource = view;
}
```

error is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.EvaluateException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot perform '=' operation on System.String and System.Int32.

Tried the ff code but still the error exists.

```
private void XMLLevel2PopulateTable(string MdNum)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = ds.Tables["Tables"];
    DataView view = new DataView(dt);
    view.RowFilter = string.Format("MD_ID = {0}", MdNum); // error here with mdNum
    dataGridView2.DataSource = view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your column is of integer type. The exception tells you that you are trying to compare string with int.

```
 view.RowFilter = string.Format("MD_ID = '{0}'", MdNum);
```